# error: conflicting types for "computeTemp" (C)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double computeTemp(double, double, double, double, double, double);

void main(void)
{

 double rm,deg,h,w,l,t;
    double final_temp;

    printf("For all calculations assume that pressure is constant at 101.325kPa,and the heat capacity of air is also constant at 0.718kJ/kg*K\n");
    printf("Please enter the number of students in the room:\n");
    scanf("%lf",&rm);
    printf("Please enter a temperature in degrees Celcius:\n");
    scanf("%lf",&deg);
    printf("Please enter the height of the room in metres (m):\n");
    scanf("%lf",&h);
    printf("Please enter the width of the room in metres (m):\n");
    scanf("%lf",&w);
    printf("Please enter the length of the room in metres (m):\n");
    scanf("%lf",&l);
    printf("Please enter a time in minutes (min.):\n");
    scanf("%lf",&t);

    final_temp = computeTemp(rm,deg,h,w,l,t,final_temp);

    printf("Number of students: %f\n",rm);
    printf("Initial temperature in degrees Celcius: %f\n",deg);
    printf("Height of room (m): %f\n",h);
    printf("Width of room (m): %f\n",w);
    printf("Length of room (m): %f\n",l);
    printf("Time elapsed (min.):%f\n",t);
    printf("Final Temperature in degrees Celcius: %f\n",final_temp);

}

double computeTemp(double num1, double num2, double num3, double num4, double num5, double num6)

{

 double temp; 

    temp = ((101.325*28.97)*(num3*num4*num5))/8.314*(num2+273.15);
    temp = temp*0.718;
    temp = (((4.8*num1*num6)*(num2+273.15))/(temp));
    temp = temp+(num2+273.15);
    temp = temp-273.15;
    return(temp);
}
```

I deleted a double from the function call and an error appears that there are too few arguments with computeTemp. i am new to c programming and using CodeBlocks so any information that can assist me in solving this problem would be very much appreciated

Comment: plz use CTRL+K to indent your code

Comment: Your argument naming scheme for the `computeTemp` is not that good. If you don't know exactly what the function is doing there is no way to understand it. Please use more descriptive names. Also, please try to avoid [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

Answer (score 3):

Your forward declaration declares `computeTemp` as

```
double computeTemp(double, double, double, double, double, double, double);
```

and the definition is

```
double computeTemp(double num1, double num2, double num3, double num4, double num5, double num6)
```

Count them; the first has seven arguments while the second only has six...

Comment: when i do that a new error appears saying that there are too many arguments to the function computeTemp

Comment: @nsquared. Please edit your post and add what you have changed it to

Comment: You're calling the computTemp functions with too many arguments. According to the your listing above you are sending down seven variables. Did you address Ben's comment correctly - you need to increase the number of arguments in the function definition to seven and keep the function declaration the same. Or if you don't need the seventh argument reduce the number to six and remove the sixth variable in the function call.

Comment: @cdcdcd Your current code has 6 parameters for your function, but you are trying to call the function with 7 parameters.

Comment: nos are you a member of the apostrophe police? :) I'm not sure what you're suggesting - I basically said the same thing but using "arguments". Strictly speaking the function takes 7 parameters but you're passing down 6 arguments. In K&R the interchange these so loosely I don't bother differentiating.